# Jquery fadeToggle Trouble

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm building a web app and am trying to incorporate animations to make it a little more pleasing to use. I'm new to the industry so I'm sure there is a better way of doing this so sorry in advance for the bad code!

I have two menus: One is for 'Sector', the other is for 'Menus'. Upon selecting a sector a few menu items will populate for that given sector. AND THEN once the Menu item has been selected the blank section on the right will populate with the actual content. (It's kind of like a dashboard?)

In any case, As you can see in the code I'm constantly toggling through which items to show and which items are to hide. (If there is a short cut way to do this please let me know!)

The problem I am running into is when I add a fadeToggle() I find that it works initially, however eventually the app glitches and will loop.

**I have written in the code that IF the pharma canvas is display == none then show the welcome message again, but it's not working**..

I want to have a high fade ideally so I can incorporate animations on the welcome menu (the big orange div that appears before clicking anything)

**Is there a better way of ensuring that once the fade happens it stops if the user selects a different menu option?**

For example: If I click Pharma, then click it again (to hide it) i want to absolutely make sure that it will 100% be hidden and not start fading again.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

    var pharmaCanvas = document.getElementById('pharmaceuticals_canvas'); 
    var welcomeCanvas = document.getElementById('welcome_canvas');
    var CK_canvas = document.getElementById('pharma_CK_canvas');
    var QL_canvas = document.getElementById('pharma_QL_canvas');


    $(pharmaCanvas).hide();
    $(pharma_dashboard).hide();
    $(pharma_CK_canvas).hide();
    $(QL_canvas).hide();


$('.menuBtns').click(function(){

        //This will decrease the left menu size on click// 
        
        $("#left_menu").toggleClass("menu_decrease");
        $(".left_menu_title").toggleClass("menu_decrease_title");


});
    
    $('#pharmBtn').click(function(){
        
        //Opens up Overview, as default
        $(pharmaCanvas).fadeToggle(3000);
        
        //opens up the PHARMA Dashboard / Right Dashboard //
        $(pharma_dashboard).toggle();
        
        //Toggles the WELCOME Dashboard which is not secific to any sector's dashboard//
        $(welcome_dashboard).toggle();
        
        //The secondary menu/ dashboard menu item will turn grey //
        $("#pharma_default").addClass("selected_item_grey");
        
        //This is for the Background  color of the menu will stay when sector is selected//
        $("#pharma_left_menu").toggleClass("selected_left_menu_title");
        
        //Hide all other canvases//
        $(welcomeCanvas).hide();
        $(pharma_CK_canvas).hide();
        $(pharma_QL_canvas).hide();
        $(welcomeCanvas).hide();
    
    })
    
    //Start Dashboard Journey Here//
    
    $('#pharma_OBtn').click(function(){
    
        $(pharmaCanvas).toggle();
        $("#pharma_default").addClass("selected_item_grey");
        $("#pharma_CK").removeClass("selected_item_grey");
        
        $(pharma_CK_canvas).hide();
        $(welcomeCanvas).hide();
        
        $(pharma_QL_canvas).hide();
    
    })

    
    $('#pharma_CKBtn').click(function(){
    
        $(pharma_CK_canvas).toggle();
        $("#pharma_CK").addClass("selected_item_grey");
        
        $("#pharma_default").removeClass("selected_item_grey");
        $("#pharma_QL").removeClass("selected_item_grey");
        $("#left_menu").addClass("");
        
        $(pharmaCanvas).hide();
        $(pharma_QL_canvas).hide();
    
    })
    
    $('#pharma_QLBtn').click(function(){
    
        $(QL_canvas).toggle();
        $("pharma_QL").addClass("selected_item_grey");
        
        $("#pharma_default").removeClass("selected_item_grey");
        $("#pharma_CK").removeClass("selected_item_grey");
        
        
        $(pharmaCanvas).hide();
        $(pharma_CK_canvas).hide();
    
    })
  
  //Our Functios Actions//
  
  var supplyChainContent = document.getElementById('our_role_sc_content');
  var researchContent = document.getElementById('our_role_rd_content');
  var commercialContent = document.getElementById('our_role_com_content');
  
  $(supplyChainContent).hide();
  $(researchContent).hide();
  $(commercialContent).hide();
  
  //On button click the content will hide or show and toggle the matching class shadows. 
    
    $('#scBtn').click(function(){
        
        $(supplyChainContent).toggle();
        $('.our_functions_wrapper').toggleClass('our_functions_shadow_red');
        $('.our_functions_wrapper').removeClass('our_functions_shadow_blue');
        $('.our_functions_wrapper').removeClass('our_functions_shadow_orange');
        
        $(researchContent).hide();
        $(commercialContent).hide();
        
    });
    
    $('#rdBtn').click(function(){

        $(supplyChainContent).hide();
        $(researchContent).toggle();
        $('.our_functions_wrapper').toggleClass('our_functions_shadow_orange');
        $('.our_functions_wrapper').removeClass('our_functions_shadow_blue');
        $('.our_functions_wrapper').removeClass('our_functions_shadow_red');
        $(commercialContent).hide();
        
    });
    
    $('#comBtn').click(function(){
    
        $(supplyChainContent).hide();
        $(researchContent).hide();
        $(commercialContent).toggle
        $('.our_functions_wrapper').toggleClass('our_functions_shadow_blue');
        $('.our_functions_wrapper').removeClass('our_functions_shadow_red');
        $('.our_functions_wrapper').removeClass('our_functions_shadow_orange');
        
    });
    
    
    
    //NOT IN USE YET: Statement will be used when multiple canvases are active//
    
    if($(pharmaCanvas).css('display')== 'none'){
        console.log("All Elements are hidden")
        $(welcomeCanvas).show();
    }
    


});
```

```css
#s4-workspace{
overflow-x: hidden! important;

}
#WebPartWPQ4{
margin-right:-20px;}
body
{
    font-family:"Arial"!important;
    
}
#tbl_CRM_A_wrapper
{   
    width: 1140px;
}
#containter_box
{
    font-family:"Arial"!important;
    margin:auto;
}
#container
{
    width:100%;
    margin:auto;
}
#contentBox {
        margin-right: 0px !important;
        margin-left:0px!important;
    }
#contentBox table table {
        padding: 5px 0px 10px 10px !important;
}

#s4-titlerow , .ms-core-sideNavBox-removeLeftMargin, #WebPartWPQ5_ChromeTitle, #ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_ctl01__ControlWrapper_RichHtmlField>p
{
    display:none !important;
}
div.article, .contentRow, #contentRow
{
    padding:0px !important;
}
.ms-webpart-chrome-title
{
display: none;
}



/* Main Section */

.main_container{

    width:1260px;
    height: 450px;
    
    

}

#canvas{

    height: 450px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.column_right{
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    width: 179px;
    border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
    margin-top: -240px;
    z-index: 3;
    height: 245px;
    background-color: #f6f6fc;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
  background: white;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  
  border-radius: 10px;
}
 
/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #dbdbdb; 
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px grey; 
  border-radius: 10px;
}

/* Handle on hover */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #b1b0b0; 
}

/* Menus */
#left_menu{
    height: 450px; 
    width: 200px;
    float: left; 
    background-color: #323896;
}

.main_menu_title{
    font-family: Arial Black;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-decoration: none!important;
    color: white!important;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.main_menu_subtitle{
    font-family: Arial Black;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: white!important;
    text-decoration: none!important;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.left_menu_title{
    font-family: Arial Black!important;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: white!important;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    height: 35px;
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-top: 9px;
    border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
    text-decoration: none!important;

    background: linear-gradient(to right, #323896 50%, #f6f6fc 50%) left;
    background-size: 200%;
    transition: .5s ease-out;
}


.left_menu_title:hover{
    background-position: right;
    color: #323896!important;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none!important;
    
}

.menu_decrease{
    width:115px!important;
    transition: all .5s linear;
    
}

.menu_decrease_title{
    font-size: 11px!important; 
}
.menuBtns{
    text-decoration: none!important;
}

.selected_left_menu_title{
    color: #323896!important;
    background: #f6f6fc!important;

}


.dashboard_menu_title{
    font-family: Arial Black;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #323896!important;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.dashboard_menu_subtitle{
    font-family: Arial Black;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #acacac!important;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
#dashboard_menu{
    height: 450px; 
    width: 200px;
    float:left;
    background-color: #f6f6fc;
    box-shadow: 4px 0 5px -2px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);
    border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
}

.dashboard_menu_selection{
    font-family: Arial Black;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #acacac!important;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 49px;
}

#greeting_section{
    background-color: #ffa000;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-left: 35px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 525px;
    height: 80px;
}

#greeting_section_1{
    background-color: #ffa000;
    margin-top: 140px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-left: 107px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 525px;
    height: 137px;
}

#greeting_section_title{
    color: white!important;
    font-family: Arial Black;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#welcome_canvas #greeting_section_title{
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#geeting_section_subTitle{
    color: white!important;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.our_role_wrapper{
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 11px 2px rgb(0 0 0 / 10%);
    margin-top: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-left: 35px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 525px;
    height: 60px;

}

#our_role_pharma_section{
    height: 100px!important;
}

.our_role_title{
    color: #323896!important;
    font-family: arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;

}

.title_wrapper_box{
    background-color: white;
    height: 30px;
    margin-left: 35px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 400px; 
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    
}

.carousel_arrow_box{
    background-color: #f25767;
    height: 20px;
    width: 53px;
    display: inline;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.arrows{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white!important;
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;

}

.role_box{
    display: inline-block;

}

#role_text{
    color: #474747!important;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-left: 5px; 
    margin-top: 5px; 

}

.functions_category_wrapper{
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 35px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 725px;
    height: 50px;
}

.functions_category_boxes{
    width: 125px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: inline-flex;
    postion: relative;
}

.functionBtn{
    text-decoration: none!important; 
    cursor: pointer; 
}

#scBtn{
    background-color: #f25767;
}

#rdBtn{
    background-color: #ffa000;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

#comBtn{
    background-color: #00b5e2;
    margin-left: 10px; 
}

.functions_category_title{
    color: white!important;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 8px;
}

#fuctions_commercial_text{
    margin-top: 17px!important;
}

.functions_category_icons{
    float: left;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 5px; 
}
#supply_chain_icon{
    width: 45px!important;
}

.our_functions_wrapper{
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 11px 2px rgb(0 0 0 / 10%);
    margin-top: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-left: 35px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 725px;
    height: 180px;
}

.our_functions_shadow_red{

    box-shadow: 1px 1px 11px 2px rgb(242 87 103 / 50%);
    
}

.our_functions_shadow_orange{

    box-shadow: 1px 1px 11px 2px rgb(255 158 0 / 50%);
    
}

.our_functions_shadow_blue{

    box-shadow: 1px 1px 11px 2px rgb(0 181 226 / 50%);
    
}

.our_docs_title{
    color: #323896!important;
    font-family: arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.our_agenda_title{
    color: #323896!important;
    font-family: arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.folder_icons{
    height: 80px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}


.center_text{
    text-align: center!important;
}

.selected_item_grey{

    color: grey!important;
    font-size: 13px;
}

.dashboard_menu_selection:hover{
    color: grey!important;
    font-size: 13px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<!-- J Query Library -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- SPServices -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.02/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js"></script>

<!-- DataTables -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">    
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.12/css/dataTables.jqueryui.min.css"> 
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



</head>

<body>


<!-- Main Content -->   

<div class="main_container" id="welcome_container">

    <div id="left_menu">
        <h1 class="main_menu_title">Sector</h1>
        <h1 class="main_menu_subtitle">Select Sector</h1>
    
        <div class="row_left_menu_item">
            <img class="left_menu_icons" src="">
            <a id="epsBtn" class="menuBtns"><h2 class="left_menu_title" id="">DONT CLICK</h2></a>
        </div>
        <div class="row_left_menu_item">
            <img class="left_menu_icons" src="">
            <a id="enterpriseBtn" class="menuBtns"><h2 class="left_menu_title" id="">NOT IMPORTANT</h2></a>
        </div>
        <div class="row_left_menu_item">
            <img class="left_menu_icons" src="">
            <a id="consumerBtn" class="menuBtns"><h2 class="left_menu_title" id="">Blah</h2></a>
        </div>

        <div class="row_left_menu_item">
            <img class="left_menu_icons" src="">
            <a id="medBtn" class="menuBtns"><h2 class="left_menu_title" id="">Blah2</h2></a>
        </div>
        <div class="row_left_menu_item">
            <img class="left_menu_icons" src="">
            <a id="pharmBtn" class="menuBtns"><h2 class="left_menu_title" id="pharma_left_menu">Pharma</h2></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="welcome_dashboard">
        <div id="dashboard_menu">
            <h1 class="dashboard_menu_title">Menus</h1>
            <h1 class="dashboard_menu_subtitle">Select Menu</h1>
            
            <div class="dashboard_menu_row">
                <h2 class="dashboard_menu_selection" style="margin-top: 100px;" >Please Select Sector to Display Menus</h2>
            </div>
        
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="pharma_dashboard">
        <div id="dashboard_menu">
            <h1 class="dashboard_menu_title">Menus</h1>
            <h1 class="dashboard_menu_subtitle">Select Menu</h1>
            <a id="pharma_OBtn">
                <div class="dashboard_menu_row">
                    <h2 class="dashboard_menu_selection" id="pharma_default">Overview</h2>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a id="pharma_CKBtn">
                <div class="dashboard_menu_row">
                    <h2 class="dashboard_menu_selection" id="pharma_CK">CK</h2>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a id="pharma_QLBtn">
                <div class="dashboard_menu_row">
                    <h2 class="dashboard_menu_selection" id="pharma_QL">Quick Links</h2>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a id="pharma_TrainBtn">
                <div class="dashboard_menu_row">
                    <h2 class="dashboard_menu_selection" id="pharma_Train">Training Materials</h2>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a id="pharma_TeamBtn">
                <div class="dashboard_menu_row">
                    <h2 class="dashboard_menu_selection" id="pharma_Team">Team Members</h2>
                </div>
            </a>
        
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Welcome Sector -->
    <div id="welcome_canvas">
        <div id="canvas">
    
            
                <!-- Column Left Has: Greeting, Role, Functions Sections-->
                <div class="column_left">
                    <!-- Greeting Section -->
                    <div id="greeting_section_1"> 
                        <h1 id="greeting_section_title" class="center_text">Welcome Platform</h1>
                        <p id="geeting_section_subTitle" class="center_text">Begin your journey by selecting a sector</p>
                    </div>

                </div>
        
        <!-- Canvas End -->
        </div>
    <!-- Canvas WRAPPER PER SECTOR End -->
    </div>
    <!-- *********************************** -->
    <!-- ******** OVERVIEW SECTION ********* -->
    <!-- *********************************** -->
    
        <div id="canvas">
            <div id="pharmaceuticals_canvas">
                <!-- Column Left Has: Greeting, Role, Functions Sections-->
                <div class="column_left">
                    <!-- Greeting Section -->
                    <div id="greeting_section"> 
                        <h1 id="greeting_section_title">Welcome to the Pharmaceuticals Dashboard</h1>
                        <p id="geeting_section_subTitle">Here you will find an overview of our process </p>
                    </div>
                        
                    <!-- Our Role Section -->
                    <div class="title_wrapper_box">
                        <div class="role_box">
                            <h1 class="our_role_title">Pharmaceuticals</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel_arrow_box"><h1 class="arrows"> < </h1> <h1 class="arrows"> > </h1></h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="our_role_wrapper" id="our_role_pharma_section">
                            <div class="our_role_section" >
                                <p id="role_text">Driven by our commitment to patients, we bring innovative products, services, and solutions to people throughout the world. We recognize the impact of serious conditions on people’s lives, and we aim to empower people through disease awareness, education and access to quality care.</p>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                        
                </div>

                <!-- Column Right Has: Docs and Contact/Our Team -->
                <div class="column_right">
                    <div class="our_docs_wrapper">
                        <h1 class="our_docs_title">Our Docs</h1>
                            <div class="our_docs_section">
                                <img class="folder_icons" src="/folder_icon.png">
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="our_agenda_wrapper">
                        <h1 class="our_agenda_title">Agenda</h1>
                            <div class="our_agenda_section">
                                <img class="folder_icons" src="/Icons/folder_icon.png">
                            </div>
                    </div>
                        
                </div>
            </div>
            
    <!-- *********************************** -->
    <!-- ************ CK SECTION *********** -->
    <!-- *********************************** -->
            <div id="pharma_CK_canvas">
                <!-- Column Left Has: Greeting, Role, Functions Sections-->
                <div class="column_left">
                    <!-- Greeting Section -->
                    <div id="greeting_section"> 
                        <h1 id="greeting_section_title">Welcome to the Pharmaceuticals Dashboard</h1>
                        <p id="geeting_section_subTitle">Customer Knowledge</p>
                    </div>
                        
                    <!-- Our Role Section -->
                    <div class="title_wrapper_box">
                        <div class="role_box">
                            <h1 class="our_role_title">Our Role</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel_arrow_box"><h1 class="arrows"> < </h1> <h1 class="arrows"> > </h1></h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="our_role_wrapper">
                            <div class="our_role_section">
                                <p id="role_text">CK</p>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                            <!-- Our Functions Section -->
    <!-- Our Functions Section -->
                    <div class="title_wrapper_box">
                        <div class="role_box">
                            <h1 class="our_role_title">Our Funtions</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="functions_category_wrapper">
                        <a class="functionBtn">
                            <div class="functions_category_boxes" id="scBtn">
                            
                                    <img class="functions_category_icons" id="supply_chain_icon" src="/Icons/Supply_Chain_icon.png"> 
                                    <h2 class="functions_category_title">Supply Chain</h2>
                                
                            </div>
                        </a>
                        <a class="functionBtn">
                            <div class="functions_category_boxes" id="rdBtn">
                        
                                    <img class="functions_category_icons" src="/Icons/R%26D_Icon.png"> 
                                    <h2 class="functions_category_title">Research & Development</h2>
                                
                            </div>
                        </a>
                        <a class="functionBtn">
                            <div class="functions_category_boxes" id="comBtn">
                                
                                    <img class="functions_category_icons" src="/Icons/commercial_icon.png"> 
                                    <h2 class="functions_category_title"  id="fuctions_commercial_text">Commmercial</h2>
                                
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    
                    </div>
                    <div class="our_functions_wrapper">
                            <div class="our_role_section">
                                
                                <div class="our_role_content" id="our_role_sc_content">
                                    <h2>Supply Chain content will go here</h2>
                                </div>
                                <div class="our_role_content" id="our_role_rd_content">
                                    <h2>Research and Development content will go here</h2>
                                </div>
                                <div class="our_role_content" id="our_role_com_content">
                                    <h2>Commercial content will go here</h2>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Column Right Has: Docs and Contact/Our Team -->
                <div class="column_right" id="column_right_ck">
                    <div class="our_docs_wrapper">
                        <h1 class="our_docs_title">Our Docs</h1>
                            <div class="our_docs_section">
                                <img class="folder_icons" src="/Icons/folder_icon.png">
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="our_agenda_wrapper">
                        <h1 class="our_agenda_title">Agenda</h1>
                            <div class="our_agenda_section">
                                <img class="folder_icons" src="/Images/SBP_Tool/Icons/folder_icon.png">
                            </div>
                    </div>
                        
                </div>
            </div>
            
            
            
    <!-- *********************************** -->
    <!-- ************ Quick Links *********** -->
    <!-- *********************************** -->
            <div id="pharma_QL_canvas">
                <!-- Column Left Has: Greeting, Role, Functions Sections-->
                <div class="column_left">
                    <!-- Greeting Section -->
                    <div id="greeting_section"> 
                        <h1 id="greeting_section_title">Welcome to the Pharmaceuticals Dashboard</h1>
                        <p id="geeting_section_subTitle">QUICK LINKS </p>
                    </div>
                        
                    <!-- Our Role Section -->
                    <div class="title_wrapper_box">
                        <div class="role_box">
                            <h1 class="our_role_title">Our Role</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel_arrow_box"><h1 class="arrows"> < </h1> <h1 class="arrows"> > </h1></h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="our_role_wrapper">
                            <div class="our_role_section">
                                <p id="role_text">CK</p>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                            <!-- Our Functions Section -->
                    <div class="title_wrapper_box">
                        <div class="role_box">
                            <h1 class="our_role_title">Our Funtions</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="functions_category_wrapper">
                        <div class="functions_category_boxes">
                            <img class="functions_category_icons" id="supply_chain_icon" src="/SBP_Tool/Icons/Supply_Chain_icon.png"> 
                            <h2 class="functions_category_title">Supply Chain</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="functions_category_boxes">
                            <img class="functions_category_icons" src="/SBP_Tool/Icons/R%26D_Icon.png"> 
                            <h2 class="functions_category_title">Research & Development</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="functions_category_boxes">
                            <img class="functions_category_icons" src="/SBP_Tool/Icons/commercial_icon.png"> 
                            <h2 class="functions_category_title"  id="fuctions_commercial_text">Commmercial</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="our_functions_wrapper">
                            <div class="our_role_section">
                                <p id="role_text">Text kdvkfnvjnvkjfnvkjfnv</p>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Column Right Has: Docs and Contact/Our Team -->
                <div id="column_right">
                    <div class="our_docs_wrapper">
                        <h1 class="our_docs_title">Our Docs</h1>
                            <div class="our_docs_section">
                                <img class="folder_icons" src="/Images/SBP_Tool/Icons/folder_icon.png">
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="our_agenda_wrapper">
                        <h1 class="our_agenda_title">Agenda</h1>
                            <div class="our_agenda_section">
                                <img class="folder_icons" src="/SRC/Images/SBP_Tool/Icons/folder_icon.png">
                            </div>
                    </div>
                        
                </div>
            </div>
        
        <!-- Canvas End -->
        </div>
        
        <!-- Main Container End -->
        
    </div>

</div>



    
    </div>

</div>
        
    
    

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a few suggestions for you:

1. In JavaScript you should stick with camel case. So `CK_canvas` would be `ckCanvas`
2. The reason you are seeing it "loop" is because your animation cycle is so long that you can queue up multiple calls to perform the animation. Also in general animations in a UI should be fast and snappy. Think .1 to .5 seconds max.
3. Make use of helper functions. For instance, you could use the following to enable or disable certain classes for the colors - this will help reduce in code duplication, which should be avoided when possible:

```js
function toggleShadowColor(color) {
  $('.our_functions_wrapper').removeClass('our_functions_shadow_orange');
  $('.our_functions_wrapper').removeClass('our_functions_shadow_blue');
  $('.our_functions_wrapper').removeClass('our_functions_shadow_red');
  switch (color) {
    case "orange":
      $('.our_functions_wrapper').addClass('our_functions_shadow_orange');
      break;
    case "blue":
      $('.our_functions_wrapper').addClass('our_functions_shadow_blue');
      break;
    case "red"
    $('.our_functions_wrapper').addClass('our_functions_shadow_red');
  }
}

//Call it like this:
toggleShadowColor("red");
```

You can also use the following to listen for end of animations if you want to prevent and enable user actions during an animation. IE disable the menu/nav or check if something is hidden or shown:

```
const animated = document.querySelector('.animated');

animated.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
  console.log('Animation ended');
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this!! I was really stressing about how much my code was repeating! I really appreciate the switch example!! I'm going to try to use it more with other repetitive cases as well.